# Volume in AVAudioRecorder

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, avaudiorecorder

I'd like to change the input volume for the AVAudioRecorder. I googled about this problem and only found solutions that increase the AVAudioPlayer's volume but I'm not interested in playing the audio on the Iphone, they are uploaded to an FTP Server.

My client wants to change volume levels while interviewing people, can this be done?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

We cannot change the volume while recording. But after recording you can process the sound and after that you can upload it to server. Many libraries are already available for this purpose. `DiracLE` is one of those.And play the file in your Mac to check the volume.

Comment: Ok thanks, this will become a responsibility for the editors then.